# Issues with lambda function in Python

Tags: python, sorting

```
map = {}

for i in words:
    if i not in map:
        map[i] = 0
    map[i] += 1
    
values = list(map.items())
values = sorted(values, key=lambda x: [x[1], x[0]], reverse=True)  
 
res = []

for i in range(len(values)-1, len(values)-1-k, -1):
    res.append(values[i][0])
return res
```

I am trying to sort by higher frequency count first and then alphabetically. How would I do this with a lambda function?

`values` is a list of tuples where the first element in tuple represents the word and the second element represents its frequency count. For example: `("hi", 2)`

For example, `["i", "love", "leetcode", "i", "love", "coding"]` should output `[('i', 2), ('love', 2), ('leetcode', 1), ('coding', 1)]`, but mine is outputting `[('love', 2), ('i', 2), ('leetcode', 1), ('coding', 1)]`.

Comment: You haven't explained what your "issue" is. Please add sample data demonstrating the problem you are having.

Comment: My issue is my code is not properly sorting elements alphabetically when their frequency counts are the same.  For example, ["i", "love", "leetcode", "i", "love", "coding"] should output [('i', 2), ('love', 2), ('leetcode', 1), ('coding', 1)], but mine is outputting [('love', 2), ('i', 2), ('leetcode', 1), ('coding', 1)].

Comment: You sorted with `reverse=True`, so they are in reverse order of frequency, and then equal frequencies are in reverse alphabetical order.

Comment: How would I fix this? Is it possible to apply reverse only to a single attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to sort by frequency descending but then alphabetically in order, you can't use `reverse=True` as that will sort the words in descending order too. Instead you can sort on `-x[1]` to sort the frequencies descending:

```
values = [('i', 2), ('love', 2), ('leetcode', 1), ('coding', 1)]

values = sorted(values, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
print(values)
```

Output:

```
[('i', 2), ('love', 2), ('coding', 1), ('leetcode', 1)]
```